# Failed to integrate SQLite in Vapor project

Tags: swift, sqlite, vapor

I am trying to integrate SQLite into a Vapor project. I have added package for `Sqlite Provider` in the `Package.swift` file as:

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/sqlite-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1)
```

and created a `sqlite.json` file, under config directory, containing

```
{
    "path": "database_name.sqlite"
}
```

After that, I ran `vapor clean && vapor xcode` to integrate sqlite into the project. Everything worked fine, except now the project shows two **Swift Compiler Error**:

> Header '/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include/sqlite3.h' not found

and

> Could not build Objective-C module 'CSQliteMac'

Can you help to resolve this issues?

Comment: It seems that SQLite is not properly installed, maybe reinstall or update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Fahim**, the `sqlite3.h` wasn't at

`/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include/sqlite3.h`

the correct location is, in my case,
`/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.17.0/include/sqlite3.h`

Just run the following command in terminal:

```
brew install sqlite
```

It will install or update if you have previously installed. At the end of completion, you will see ***Summary*** something like:

> ==> Summary
>     /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.17.0: 11 files, 2.9MB

which is giving the `sqlite` location, `/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.17.0`.

Now click the first error message, it will take you to the `module.modulemap` file. Replace the location and build. It will build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you might want to do:

1: First check that the `/usr/local/opt/sqlite` folder and the `includes` subfolder inside that folder exist.

2: If the `/usr/local/opt/sqlite` folder does not exist, you might need to install SQLite. The easiest way to do this would be via Homebrew - if you have it installed. Just run the following command from Terminal:

```
brew install sqlite
```

3: If you don't have Homebrew, then you'll have to decide whether you want to install Homebrew or if you want to try installing the SQLite source manually.

Hopefully, this helps :)

Comment: My mac does have `Homebrew`, also pre-installed SQLite. Therefore, didn't install again. Do you think I should uninstall and re-install it?

Comment: I'd suggest that you first check to see if the include file mentioned in your error message is present. If it is present, I'd suspect some other error. But if it is not present at the specified path, then do try uninstalling and re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly mysql installation problem, follow below steps to run mysql vapour app.

1. First un-install installed mysql.
2. Install brew from [here](https://brew.sh) or run below command

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
3. Run below command to install mysql

   ```
   brew install mysql
   ```
4. Run below command for linking

   ```
   brew link mysql
   ```
5. Run below command to start mysql server

   ```
   mysql.sever start
   ```
6. Run below command for root user

   ```
   mysql -uroot
   ```
7. Then run below command to SET ROOT user password

   ```
   SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD(‘admin’);
   ```
8. Create database before run your project, using below command

   ```
   create database your_database_name_goes_here;
   ```
9. Then run your project, no doubt after this your project will run.

> Note1:- Don't forget to add mysql.json in you project as described [here](https://github.com/vapor/mysql-provider).

.

> Note2:- Also don't forget to add provider and prepare database table using model class as below.

```
 try drop.addProvider(VaporMySQL.Provider.self)
 drop.preparations = [ModelClass.self]
```

I have created a demo project on [Github here](https://github.com/AnandSuthar/vapor-mysql), you can try.

Comment: that's nice. But you forgot something, I'm not working on `mysql`, but `SQLite`. Anyway, thanks.